# Is it necessary JMX provider (or application server) to use JMX?

Tags: java, jms, jmx

This is similar case like JMS and JMS provider? Or can I use JMX without application server and JMX provider?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Absolutely. JMX is part of the standard JavaSE6 API. Every Java5+ VM has an embedded JMX server.

JavaEE appservers typically make heavy use of JMX, but it's by no means limited to them.

The comparison with JMS only goes so far - yes, there is a separation between interface and implementation, and yes, different implementations have proprietary network protocols to access them remotely, but JMX is an awful lot simpler than JMS.